# Integrating Neodash (Neo4j Dashboard) as an iFrame into a React JS Application

Tags: reactjs, iframe, neo4j, neodash

We have a React JS application and I want to include the [Neodash](https://neodash.graphapp.io/) (Neo4j Dashboard) as a component within my app. I have seen that Neodash provides a user-friendly interface for exploring Neo4j databases, and I'd like to leverage its functionality in my React application.

Is it possible to embed the Neodash dashboard as an iFrame within my React JS app? If so, what would be the recommended approach to achieve this integration? Are there any potential challenges or limitations I should be aware of while attempting this integration? Any insights, examples, or code snippets on how to implement it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!